# "Super expression must either be null or a function, not object" error

Tags: realm, react-native

I use example code from https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js.

```
'use strict';

import Realm from 'realm';

class Todo extends Realm.Object {}
Todo.schema = {
    name: 'Todo',
    properties: {
        done: {type: 'bool', default: false},
        text: 'string',
    },
};

class TodoList extends Realm.Object {}
TodoList.schema = {
    name: 'TodoList',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        items: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Todo'},
    },
};

export default new Realm({schema: [Todo, TodoList]});
```

When I run this, I got

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

error.

[image]

I am using

```
"react": "^0.14.8",
"react-native": "^0.25.1",
"realm": "^0.12.0",
```

How can I solve this issue? Thank you for any tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the newest version `0.13.0` which is coming out shortly. You can try the release candidate now by setting the version to `0.13.0-rc` in your package.json