# Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I get **Super expression must either be null or a function, not object** error when I run **index.js**

I see another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328215/super-expression-must-either-be-null-or-a-function-not-object-error) with similar error message. But looks like that is related to react!

## base.js

```
   export default class Base{
        constructor(title){
            console.log(title);
        }
    }
```

## Class1.js

```
import * as Base from './base';

export default class Class1 extends Base{
    constructor(title){
        super(title);
    }
}
```

## index.js

```
import * as Class1 from './class1';
'use strict';

function check() {
    var c = new Class1('from Index.js');
}

check();
```

## .babelrc

{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-1"
    ]
}

## dependencies

```
dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-export-extensions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1"
  }
```

Please help! Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing namespace imports (`* as …`) that create namespace objects in your variables, which are not functions indeed like the error message says. You will want to import the default exports:

```
import Base from './base';
```

and

```
import Class1 from './class1';
```

Answer (score 2):

When you import, you are importing the entire js file, which is an object. You need to import just the class from your js file.

To use just a class do

```
import {myMember} from 'my-module';
```

Which imports just the member called `myMember`.

You are doing this

```
import * as myModule from 'my-module';
```

Which imports all of the members of your file as sub-members of the `myModule` object.

See [Importing in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (examples from here)